# About the closedness of a given set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

In Apostol's Mathematical Analysis book, it is said that the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap (a,b) $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, where $a$ and $b$ are irrationals. Here $\mathbb{Q}$ represents the set of rational numbers. How can I prove this?

**Apostol's definition of open set:** A set $S \subset M$ is open in $M$ if every point of $S$ is an interior point of $S$.

**Definition of an interior point:** A point $a$ in the set $S$ is an interior point if it has a neighbourhood which lies entirely in $S$.

**Definition of closed set:** A set $S$ is closed in $M$ if $M - S$ is open in $M$.

**My confusion:** Isn't every rational in $(a,b)$ has a neighbourhood which lies entirely in $(a,b)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: Also this highly depends on your definition of "closed set". There are several different, common, equivalent definitions, so the best help you could reasonably get would appeal to your definition

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b) = \mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b]$?

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: Your edit makes it seem you think closed sets cannot be open (this is a common misconception).  It is perfectly consistent for $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$ be be both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But in the book it just says it is closed. Shouldn't it say both open and closed?

Comment: Why did they closed my question? I was just trying to understand the concepts, not trying to solve any homework question without any effort. This is not a homework question, it is just an example given in the text and i was trying to understand

Comment: Yes, every rational in $(a,b)$ has a neighbourhood which lies entirely in $(a,b)$. This proves that $\Bbb Q \cap (a,b)$ is open in $\Bbb Q$, but that's not what you are supposed to prove. You need to prove that it's closed. So use the same argument to show that its complement $(-\infty,a)\cup (b, \infty)$ is open.

Comment: Given the context in which OP is asking, I do not regard this question as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768061/set-of-rational-numbers-bounded-between-two-irrationals-is-a-closed-set but those who find this question via web search may be interested in it. (The answers provide proofs from slightly different starting points and this other post's OP is familiar with abstract metric spaces.)

Comment: Sulam (deletion and copy-paste of my comment from 8 hours ago+1 more hint): you *must* replace your last paragraph ("**My confusion**") with: **Now things are clear:** by definition of "closed", what I must prove is ... and this, by definition of "open", reduces to proving .... So, let us prove that every point of ... is an interior point of it, i.e. every *rational* in $ (-\infty,a]\cup[b,+\infty)$ has a neighborhood  which lies entirely in it.

Comment: So it is both open and closed but i don't understand why Apostol randomly choose to emphasize one thing over the other. It is like symmetry breaking in physics. I suppose him to say it is both open and closed in order to prevent any confusion that may arise in minds.

Comment: Please Sulam, again: do improve the end of your post if you now understood (or edit a [self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)). Nothing to do with symmetry breaking of course, and Apostol did not "randomly" emphasized the closedness. The openness is obvious since for *every* topological space $X,$ subspace $Y\subset X,$ and open subset $U$ of $X,$ $Y\cap U$ is always an open subset of $Y.$